# java compiler error for hw

Tags: java, compiler-errors

can someone help me and see if how to fix this?

this is the error I got can someone tell me what i did wrong

Waypoint.java:58: error: ')' expected
      return distance(Travelable otherTravelable) / speed;
                                ^
Waypoint.java:58: error: illegal start of expression
      return distance(Travelable otherTravelable) / speed;
                                                ^
Waypoint.java:58: error: not a statement
      return distance(Travelable otherTravelable) / speed;
                                                  ^
3 errors

```
   }
   public double toDistance (Travelable otherTravelable)
   {
      return distance(otherTravelable.getPoint());
   }
   public double toTime (Travelable otherTravelable)
   {
      return toDistance(Travelable otherTravelable) / speed;
   }
   public Point2D.Double getPoint()
   {
      return this;
   }
   public Point2D.Double getPoint (Travelable otherTravelable)
   {
      return otherTravelable.getPoint();
   }
```

Comment: Your assignment isn't really relevant here, nor is most of your code. If you're just interested in why you've got a particular compile-time error, you should *just* post a short but complete program demonstrating that error and nothing else, along with the exact error message and what you expected the code to do. The wall of text at the start of your question is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method you don't specify the types of the arguments.

Change

```
distance(Travelable otherTravelable) / speed
```

to

```
distance(otherTravelable) / speed
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line by removing type of parameter when calling the method:

```
toDistance(Travelable otherTravelable) / speed;
```

To

```
toDistance(otherTravelable) / speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put

Travelable otherTravelable in the return line of toTime.
just return

```
 return toDistance(otherTravelable) / speed;
```